# Is there a way to know if and why iOS terminated your app?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I'm trying to debug an issue with my iPhone app that seems to be getting terminated while running on the device (it never happens in the simulator).  The app is for iOS 8 only.

Once app enters the background (via the user hitting the home button) I start Significant-Change Location service.  When a location updates happens while the app is suspended the system should put the app in the background where I then send an update to my server with the location.  That operation is wrapped in a proper beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to allow me the time needed to make the network call.

It appears though my app is getting terminated by the system because sometimes when I resume the app from the suspended state it is no longer in the view last seen when minimizing but is back at the root controller as if starting from a fresh launch.  It does not appear to be due to a crash as I do not see it in the crash log nor is New Relic reporting such.  The app is suspended though, not terminated, probably because it is getting launched again into the background from a location update.

The question is, is there a way to know that my app was indeed terminated by the system, and if so, for what reason(memory, exceeding background execution time, etc.) and at what time.  Is there a log kept somewhere containing this information?

I'm under the impression I can not use applicationWillTerminate because the docs say this is not called when an app is suspend.

Comment: Check the device console for clues.

Comment: Wouldn't this require the phone attached to the laptop constantly? The problem happens randomly over the course of hours.  Is that data logged somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You may check in Devices page. (Shortcut is Command + Shift + 2)

Comment: It's not a crash though. I've looked in that log and there is no information about my app.

Comment: if it's not the crash, you may have to look at device log. It would be great if you use NSLog as detail as possible. And the device logs will be cleared from device automatically if time passed.

Comment: I can't use NSLog because the system doesn't tell me when it is terminating my app and thus I'm not able to log anything.

Comment: Various parts of the system use that log to announce why things are happening.  It may not solve anything but you won't know without looking.

Comment: @PhillipMills is there a way to increase the history depth of the console log or to write it continuously to a file?  I have looked at the console log but the issue is it's only an hour or so deep and the bug happens randomly over the course of hours.  I have so far been unable to spot anything in the logs related to terminating my app.